# nth root of unity problem for homework

Tags: roots-of-unity

I'm super confused right now with this problem and any kind of mini lecture would be awesome. Thank you

Let $ω = e^{2πi/n}$
, where $n$ is a positive integer. Prove that

(a) $1 · ω · ω^2
· · · ω^{n−1} = (−1)^{n−1}$
.

Comment: Hint: $0+1+2+\dots+n-1 = n(n-1)/2$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. your hint helped

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
To avoid downvotes in future questions, please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$1\cdot\omega\cdot\omega^2\cdots\omega^{n-1}=\omega^{1+2+\ldots+(n-1)}$$

> Using that $e^{\pi i}=-1$, and that $1+2+\ldots+(n-1)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, the product becomes $$\omega^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}\cdot\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}=(-1)^{n-1}$$